# Query to show two columns of single column from table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I need some help with query writing. I have a table as in SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f51a

I need a result set as below, i.e: The query should show three columns, first is name,second is 'One' and third is 'two'. It shows data in col 'one' only if that name has value 'one' in tbl1 else it should stay blank. Similary third column should show value only if 'Name' has corresponding 'two'value.

```
Name    |   One |   Two
--------+-------+----------
Jig     |   Yes |   Yes  
Mig     |       |   Yes  
Dig     |   Yes |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name,
      IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Book ='one' THEN 'Yes' END),'') as One,
      IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Book='two' THEN 'Yes' END),'') as Two
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY Name
```

**NB:** For `oracle`, use `NVL` instead of `IFNULL`.

Result:

```
NAME    ONE   TWO
Dig     Yes 
Jig     Yes   Yes
Mig           Yes
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f51a/8).

Comment: My actual database is heavier and query is huge. With this condition it throws error- not a single group function. Is there any other way to do it when many tables are joined. The query runs fine with condition : Select Where Book = 'one' but cannot write Book='two' also in where condition. Else it joins and returns null row.

Comment: Not a single group function.

Comment: @user1630575: What is the `WHERE` clause you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Using Pivot in 11g+ and above:

```
select *
  from tbl1
  pivot (max('Yes') for book in ('one' as one, 'two' as two) );
```

output:

```
| NAME |    ONE |    TWO |
|------|--------|--------|
|  Dig |    Yes | (null) |
|  Jig |    Yes |    Yes |
|  Mig | (null) |    Yes |
```

Sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d09cf9/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Query

```
select * from tbl1;



select name
      ,max(decode(book,'one','yes','-')) as one
      ,max(decode(book,'two','yes','-')) as two

      from tbl1

group by name;
```